# How to add timestamp with interval starting from Current time with interval 1 minutes for every row in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In example, I have something like,

| Number_index |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| etc |

for example, using NOW() will give time stamp "10/24/2022 12:00:00"
I want to add timestamp which will be something like

| Number_index | Time_Stamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10/24/2022 12:00:00 |
| 2 | 10/24/2022 12:01:00 |
| 3 | 10/24/2022 12:02:00 |
| 4 | 10/24/2022 12:03:00 |
| etc | etc |

Would you please explain how to do that in mysql?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the [`TIMESTAMPADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampadd) function here:

```sql
SELECT Number_index,
       TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, Number_index - 1, NOW()) AS Time_Stamp
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Number_index;
```

The above is one option if you want *view* your output as described.  If instead you want to *update* your table, then use:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET Time_Stamp = TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE, Number_index - 1, NOW());
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much, it's working and it's all that I need.